# Replacing data from dataframe with data from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe and a csv file.

In the csv file, I have about 30 columns, including one column of ZIP codes (e.g., "10001", "08983", "85321"). CSV is 3400 rows x 30 columns.

In the dataframe, I have a column of ZIP codes and a matching column of scores:

```
zipcode  score
99780    2.250000
99801    2.719083
99824    2.721311
99827    2.285714
99835    2.534783
99901    2.501558
[27688 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to go to my csv file, look at each ZIP code, match the ZIP code up with the dataframe, and add a new column that notes the score that's stored in the dataframe. I would also be OK with just flat out replacing the ZIP code in the csv file with the score in the dataframe, if that's faster.

The reason why `.replace` isn't going to work is because I don't want to manually enter all 27688 ZIP codes and say what those should be replaced by.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Here's what a row in the CSV file currently looks like:

```
Name     Age     DOB     Gender     Hair Color     Eye Color     ZIP
John Doe 22      6-10    Male       Brn            Brn           99780
```

And here's what I want it to look like:

```
Name     Age     DOB     Gender     Hair Color     Eye Color     ZIP     Score
John Doe 22      6-10    Male       Brn            Brn           99780   2.250000
```

I'm also OK with the "Score" column flat-out replacing the ZIP column.

Comment: The merge example I posted below should accomplish this very easily. Import the csv into a separate dataframe and then merge the two dataframes based on the related column.

Comment: In order to get it back into a csv, you would use df3.to_csv('file.csv')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried loading the csv into a list and then looping through the items in the list.

```
import csv
sFile = "myfile.csv"
with open(sFile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    yourList = list(reader)

for item in yourList:
    #search and replace based on each item
```

You can also try **merge** from pandas.

**Update: Using Merge**

Here is an example of using merge:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[12345,"Atlanta"],[54321,"Orlando"]], columns=['Zip','City'])

df2 = pd.read_csv('Zip.csv')

df3 = pd.merge(df,df2,how="left", )

print (df3)
```

The result:

```
     Zip     City     State
0  12345  Atlanda   Georgia
1  54321  Orlando   Florida
```

Comment: I think I'm confused -- for the first method using `import csv`, seems like that's going to be a resource hog. And also, I don't know how to get that to search through every row in my initial dataframe.

And for merge -- I'm looking at the documentation, and I'm not sure that this is doing what I want it to do? There will be multiple records in the CSV file that share the same ZIP code -- should a merge work even if that's the case? And also, since there will be some ZIP codes in the original database that don't match with the CSV file, will it create thousands of extraneous rows?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the final result. The update I posted (using "Merge") creates a data frame that contains the original data set along with the information in the csv file. You can then either export the data or do something else with it.

Comment: I'll add an example of what the records currently look like in the CSV file, and what I want them to look like. Edit should pop up in ~5 mins.

Comment: It ended up working! I had a few more problems with my data (that's my fault -- nothing wrong with your idea), so I thought I'd just c/p what I did below.

`df2 = pd.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv') \\\\\\
df2['Zip5'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['Zip5'], errors='coerce') \\\\\\
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df_averages, how='left', left_on='Zip5', right_index=True)`